# Center content of a itextsharp cell C#

Tags: c#, itext

I am working on a salary settlement format in C #, with itexsharp to generate the pdf file.

But I can not control the alignment of the contents of the PdfPTable / PdfPCell cells.

I have this code:

```
        /*datos del LA LIQUIDACIÓN*/
        //1° linea
        phrase.Font = new Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD));
        phrase.Add("H A B E R E S");
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
        cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        cell2.PaddingTop = -7;
        cell2.AddElement(phrase);
        cell2.Colspan = 3;
        cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table2.AddCell(cell2);                
        phrase.Clear();
```

But it gives me this result:

[image]

The contents of the cell where it is for example the text "HABERES", I need that it is aligned to the center, but it is aligned to the left.

I have read this post in the past ["Right aligning text in PdfPCell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607970/right-aligning-text-in-pdfpcell?noredirect=1&lq=1) , and I have done everything that is eaten, except to take a "different road", what nevers is mentioned ... what can I do then?

Comment: One of the reasons why we have rewritten iText from scratch with iText 7, is that fact that **many developers don't read the documentation**. As a result, they don't understand the difference between *text mode* and *composite mode*. iText 7 is much more fool-proof, which leads to the quesiton: why are you still using iText 5 instead of iText 7?

Comment: Dear Bruno Lowagie, its documentation is directed to java, itext and I suppose it is completely correct. But as you can see, I'm working on C # with itextsharp. I have used, to build my project, code I have found in various examples. Because itextsharp documentation is quite skewed, can you help me with this?

Comment: There are some simple rules that every self-respecting C# developer can use: when a Java method starts with a lower case; make it an upper case. When a Java method starts with get or set; remove get or set, and use the properties approach. Please read the other answer, and apply what I say in that other answer. (To be continued...)

Comment: The other answer is about the difference between **text mode** (where you set the alignment on the cell level: `cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;`) and **composite mode** (in which case the alignment of the cell is ignored). You are using **composite mode**, hence the line `cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;` is ignored. You should either switch to text mode, or set the alignment at the level of the `phrase`. Is there something you don't understand about this answer?

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the text mode, since I have not been able to change the alignment of the Phrase class, if it has worked with the Paragraph class. I will post the answer, please give a vote. Again thank you very much..

Comment: Wel, I have posted an answer that works, so no need to post your own answer. Just up-vote (and accept) mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has worked for me, changing the composition mode, since I have not been able to change the alignment of the Phrase class, if it has worked with the Paragraph class.:

```
            /*datos del LA LIQUIDACIÓN*/
            //1° linea
            paragraph.Clear();
            paragraph.Font = new Font(FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD));
            paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;//here is the change
            paragraph.Add("H A B E R E S");
            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
            cell2.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            cell2.PaddingTop = -7;
            cell2.AddElement(paragraph);
            cell2.Colspan = 3;
            table2.AddCell(cell2);
            paragraph.Clear();
```

This Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As documented on many places, there is a difference between **text mode** (where you set the alignment on the cell level: `cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;`) and **composite mode** (in which case the alignment of the cell is ignored).

You are using **composite mode**, hence the line `cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;` is ignored. You should either switch to text mode, or set the alignment at the level of the phrase.

> The difference between **text mode** and **composite mode** exists
>   **regardless of the programming language you use.** The answer remains.

You have a `Phrase` object:

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("H A B E R E S", font);
```

Note that I changed your code, because you are creating a `Font` and a `Phrase` in a really awkward way.

You create a `Cell` to which you add the `Phrase`:

```
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
    cell2.AddElement(phrase);
    table2.addCell(cell2);
```

As you are using the `AddElement()` method, you are working in **composite mode**. That is also awkward, because there is no reason why you'd need composite mode.

As documented, the following line is ignored:

```
 cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

That line **only works in text mode.**

To fix the problem, you have two options:

**Option #1:** go to text mode

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("H A B E R E S", font);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(phrase);
cell2.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
table2.addCell(cell2);
```

**Option #2:** set the alignment at the element level, not the cell level

```
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("H A B E R E S", font);
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
cell2.AddElement(p);
table2.addCell(cell2);
```

Note that I used a `Paragraph` in option 2. It doesn't really make sense to use a `Phrase` in **composite mode**.

**SUMMARIZED:** it really matters at which level you set the alignment.

- In **text mode**, you set the alignment at the level of the cell, **NOT** at the level of its contents.
- In **composite mode**, you set the alignment at the level of the contents, **NOT** at the level of the cell.

It's as simple as that.